# Java: Adding events to dynamically created components

Tags: java, events, dynamic, draggable

I'm building a UI in Java. I want to create new components, like a JLabel, using a button. So every time I click a button it creates a new JLabel and places them in a specific JPanel.

Then, I want to be able to do some things with the labels based on how the user clicks on them.

With a left mouse press I want them to be able to drag the labels around the screen.

With a right mouse click I want to be open a new window where certain data can be entered, tied to the label (which might involve dynamically creating variables).

I've been toying around with some code I've Googled around for. I can get a button to create new labels in a panel, but when I try to get them to drag, I can only get one label at a time to appear, and after a second button press, moving the label isn't smooth, it jumps around.

I haven't even tried to implement any of the right mouse click things yet. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

```
public class Testing {

    JFrame frame;

 //Launch the application.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Testing window = new Testing();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    });
}

 //Create the application.

public Testing() {
    initialize();
    }

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    JPanel area;
    JButton btnCreate;
    JLabel dragLabel;

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 511, 542);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    area = new JPanel();
    area.setBounds(10, 11, 477, 404);
    frame.getContentPane().add(area);
    area.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    btnCreate = new JButton("Create Label");
    dragLabel = new JLabel("Drag Me");
    btnCreate.setBounds(10, 425, 477, 67);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnCreate);
    btnCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            area.add(dragLabel);
            area.revalidate();


    DragListener drag = new DragListener();
    dragLabel.addMouseListener(drag);
    dragLabel.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
    }
    });

  }
}

class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
Point location;
MouseEvent pressed;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    pressed = me;
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
{
    if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(me)){
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
         }
     }
}
```

EDIT - I'm fairly certain the primary issue is in how the JLabel itself is being added to the panel. Every time the button is being pushed it's adding the same label over again, and this is gumming up the works.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to deal with that. I've done a bit more digging, and since dynamic variables aren't possible, I'm going to have to use an array or a map or some sort. With that, it appears I can declare arrays of components. Would something like that be necessary for my purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Really odd stuff in your code. I don't want to go everything, and I'm not an expert by any stretch of the imagination, but I tried to remove redundant or contradictory stuff. I suspect a part of what you did was just copy pasting bits without really fitting them into the code.

Anyway, you needed to create the label inside the listener, so that it creates a new one everytime you click. Otherwise you only ever create one label and just reuse the same everytime.

I implemented a dialog on right click to enter the label name, don't know what you wanted to do but at least it detects right clicks.

Also in general it's easier to use layout managers instead of hardcoding everything. Here you had a borderlayout but were ignoring it.

```
class Main {

    //Launch the application.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrageableLabel window = new DrageableLabel();
    }
}

public class DrageableLabel {

    public DrageableLabel() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Container area = frame.getContentPane();
        area.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton btnCreate = new JButton("Create Label");
        btnCreate.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    /* 
                    This is where you create your new window
                    for now I've added a dialog that takes a string parameter and creates a label with that string
                    I moved the method code to create a new drageable label outside the actionlistener to make it less confusing and reuseable
                    Either build w-e you want directly in here
                    or call a method that does it (which I prefer)
                     */
                    String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your message", "Messages", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
                    addDrageableLabel(string, area);
                } else if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    addDrageableLabel("Drag me", area);
                }
            }
        });
        area.add(btnCreate, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 511, 542);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // This is the method that creates and adds a drageable label
    public void addDrageableLabel(String labelName, Container container) {
        JLabel dragLabel = new JLabel(labelName);
        container.add(dragLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.validate();

        DragListener drag = new DragListener();
        dragLabel.addMouseListener(drag);
        dragLabel.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
    }
}

class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter {

    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        pressed = me;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, most of what was there, with the exception of the DragListener class, was set up by Eclipse. I was toying around with their GUI components.

In any case, I appreciate your help. It got me to the next step.

Again, what I would like to do is allow each label to open their own window with a right click. The window will include things like a text box to input strings, and a drop down box. So for instance, the string data would be connected to the label, and the drop down box would change the labels background.

Comment: Ok, sorry for assuming things. I updated the answer with more comments in the code. I had made it with a dialog window that has a textfield and that textfield was used as a parameter to create a label. If you want more stuff you'll probably have to create a new Frame with w/e you want in it.

Comment: New problem...every time I add a new component to the JPanel all the other components reset their positions. This is clearly an issue with Layouts and the revalidate() method. How do I avoid this? I want all previously created Labels to remain precisely where they are until a user manually changes it. I was thinking just using a null layout, but people tend to want to avoid using it.

Comment: `validate()` can be called on any container, what you can do is have different elements inside different containers inside your frame and only validate the container you want to.